# Login Screen gets stuck after entering password on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, login, password, sddm

On Kubuntu here. When I enter my password on the login screen and press enter, all the buttons slightly fade and the screen just gets stuck with only the mouse cursor really being able to move. Nothing is clickable.

I pressed `Ctrl + Alt + F3` which brought up a fullscreen terminal and logged in then `startx`. Even the `startx` stayed stuck unless I held `Ctrl + C`, only then would I get into my GUI and be able to type this.

I went into System Settings and changed the lockscreen to "Breeze" but nope, it still stayed stuck after entering password.

Someone on another thread said to use `systemctl default` but that didn't work for me. Others said to change the lockscreen to "Plasma" which isn't even an option for me (probably because those threads were outdated)

I'm a newbie to Kubuntu (newbie to Linux in general, really) and I'm not sure what to do. Here's what I've installed so far:

Kvantum Engine

A theme called "Sweet KDE"

Latte Dock

PulseAudio Volume Control

GRUB Customizer (although I doubt this did anything)

That's about it really. Everything is up-to-date too. Any suggestions? Thanks, have a great day :D

Comment: Do you have another desktop environments installed?

Comment: No, just KDE really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [a suggestion by this person](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/r7srgc/comment/hn2oeal/), this is how I solved the problem:

1. Log into a TTY <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
2. Remove the `.Xauthority` file from your home directory:

   ```
   rm ~/.Xauthority
   ```
3. Reboot